# Extjs 3.4 : get value from the other editable field

Tags: extjs, combobox, datagridcomboboxcolumn

here's my code :

```
{header: "Kabupaten", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'id_k',
        renderer: function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store) {
            return rend_kab(value);
        },
        editor: new Ext.form.ComboBox({
            listeners: {
                beforequery: function(qe){
                qe.combo.store.setBaseParam('id_p', "VALUE FROM THE OTHER FIELD");
                }, 
                scope:this
            },
            store : kab,
            valueField: 'id_k',
            displayField: 'nm_kb',
            triggerAction: 'all'
        })
    },
    {header: "Provinsi", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'id_p',
        renderer: function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store) {
            return rend_prov(value);
        },
        editor: new Ext.form.ComboBox({
            store : prov,
            valueField: 'id_p',
            displayField: 'nm_p',
            triggerAction: 'all'
        })
    }
```

See The Text "VALUE FROM THE OTHER FIELD", i want it change to value from field 'id_p' in same row...
How can i do that?
Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

you can go with ,

```
  editor: new Ext.form.ComboBox({
            listeners: {
                beforequery: function(qe){
//If you have checkbox selection model then 
// to get rowIndex need to catch row in which combobox is present. using 
//this.parent.getSelectionModel().getSelected()
                    qe.combo.store.setBaseParam('id_p', gridStore.getAt(rowIndex).get("id_p"));

                }, 
                scope:this
            },
            store : kab,
            valueField: 'id_k',
            displayField: 'nm_kb',
            triggerAction: 'all'
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access a component/variable in different ways:

Lets say you have two comboboxes:

```
var ComboBoxP = Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox',{
        id: 'CBP', //used for example 2
        valueField: 'id_p',
        displayField: 'nm_p'
});

var ComboBoxKB = Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox',{
        id: 'CBKB', //used for example 2
        valueField: 'id_k',
        displayField: 'nm_kb',
});
```

1) Just use the variable.

```
SetParam( ComboBoxP.getValue() + ComboBoxKB.getValue() );
```

2) Using an id and getComponent (getCmp for short, this is not a recommended way because the id needs to be unique)

```
SetParam( Ext.getCmp('CBP').getValue() + Ext.getCmp('CBKB').getValue() );
```

3) Look for the component in your Parent containers. For this method you need a good structure in your app and a good knowledge of the up/down selectors.

```
 this.up('form').down('combobox').getValue();
```

Comment: but when i open the other 'id_k' combo, 'id_p' is close...
cause it change to the ordinary text...

Comment: When the combobox is closed you still can retrieve the value which is selected.. if you need another value you can access your store.